# Count number of members each month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like so

```
--Member--
ID char(10),
Name (nvarchar(50),
joiningDay date,
exitDay date
```

How can I count total number of member each month with a selected period of time with member that has exit will not be counted in that month
and the result should be like:
Start from month 1 to month 10

```
Month     totalOfMember
  1           5
  2           6
  3           9
 ...         ...
  10         35
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select number of members joined in a month

```
select month(joiningday)[Month],sum(case when month(joiningday)=month(exitday) then 0 else 1 end)TotalOfMember
from Member where joiningDay>='1 jan 2020' and joiningDay<'1 jan 2021'
group by month(joiningday)
order by [Month]
```

But I would suggest to use `Format(datevalue,'yyyy MM')` to count member month and year wise instead of only month. 01 can be repeated in a date range if there are two January but `2020 01` and `2021 01` will be uniquely identified.

```
 select Format(joiningday,'yyyy MM') [Month],sum(case when Format(joiningday,'yyyy MM') = Format(exitday,'yyyy MM') then 0 else 1 end)TotalOfMember
    from Member where joiningDay>='1 jan 2020' and joiningDay<'1 jan 2021'
    group by Format(joiningday,'yyyy MM')
    order by [Month]
```

Or if you want to have month wise cumulative count for members :

```
 select Format(joiningday,'yyyy MM') [Month],sum(case when Format(joiningday,'yyyy MM') = Format(exitday,'yyyy MM') then 0 else 1 end)over(order by Format(joiningday,'yyyy MM')) TotalOfMember
    from Member where joiningDay>='1 jan 2020' and joiningDay<'1 jan 2021'
    group by Format(joiningday,'yyyy MM')
    order by [Month]
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the table to itself to eliminate same-month exiters:

```
select
   year(a.joinjngday) Year,
   month(a.joiningday) Month,
   count(*) total
from Member a
join Member b on a.ID = b.ID
  and month(b.exitday) = month(a.joinjngday)
  and year(b.exitday) = year(a.joiningday)
where b.ID is null -- exclude same month exits
group by month(a.joiningday)
order by year(a.joinjngday), month(a.joiningday)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to do this is to use a cumulative sum.  Basically, you want a + count and - count for each month based on the number of members who join and leave.  I would approach this as:

```
with changes as (
      select dateformparts(year(dte), month(dte), 1) as yyyymm,
             sum(inc) as month_changes
      from members m cross apply
           (values (joiningday, 1),
                   (exitday, -1)
           ) v(dte, inc)
     )
select yyyymm, sum(month_changes)
from changes
group by yyyymm
order by yyyymm;
```

If you want this for a particular period of time, then filter the above.  Also, this will not contain months that have no changes.

If you wanted this for just a handful of months -- even those with no changes -- then you might find that explicit counting is simpler:

```
select d.dte,
       (select count(*)
        from members m
        where m.joiningday <= eomonth(d.dte) and
              m.exitday > eomonth(d.dte)
       ) as members_in_month
from (values (convert(date, '2021-01-01')),
             (convert(date, '2021-02-01')),
             (convert(date, '2021-03-01'))
     ) d(dte);
```